# How to show loader while preparing the table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Am preparing dynamic table(columns are depends on the data) using large data(ex: 50000 rows). To prepare these many records its taking 1 min time to render. To know table is rendering am showing a loader. But the problem is loader is not showing while preparing the table. Can you suggest me how to overcome this problem.

```
$('.loader').show(); 

preparingTable(data); // Preparing table by looping on data

$('.loader').hide();
```

Comment: Don't load more rows * 2 than you can see on the screen once, lazy load or paginate them

Comment: Can you show some code that you have issue with?

Comment: Previously it is paging only, but now my requirement is changed, i need to load entire data. Its rendering but, its taking more time to load.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.loader').show(); 
$.get( "getdata.html", function( data ) {
 $( ".result" ).html( data );
 $('.loader').hide();
});
```

If that was the idea, then you can use $.get in jQuery.
Make the `preparingTable(data);` in some other file.
Result will be show in the class`result`.

**getdata.html**

```
preparingTable(data);
```

Comment: You saying that, i need to prepare the table inside the `getdata.html`. Preparation the entire html i need to add in the result.

Comment: Yes That will be a good idea. The table is fetched and loading will be shown    for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use ajax for this.

1) Specify some place where you want to show your preloader.
2) When you request data, in your ajax function you can find that specified place and output your preloader there.
3) When you get ajax response, you just output your data to that place overwriting the preloader.

Comment: Yes, but entire data is available in the client side only.

Comment: You mean that you need to show your loader only once? When the user first opens your page with that data?

Comment: One request is sent to server, entire data will get from the server. After getting the response, based on the some filters on client side, the table will prepare. The preparation of the table is not in the ajax success call back.

Comment: May be because it's overwritten by some output from this 
preparingTable(data); Or because it is shown under some background of a layer.

Comment: Try to comment 
preparingTable(data); and check if your loader is actually shown on the page.

Comment: But I guess it is because your loader shows and hides faster than your preparingTable is compleated.

Comment: The dummy solution would be using timers

Answer (score -1):

@michael give a good solution to this answer.

here is a way if you want doing some cheat...:P

```
..
..
<image or some loading animation object display here>

<!-- generating looooong table row -->

<script>
  //remove or hide your loading info object 
</script>
..
..
```

Comment: I just now added sample snippet. Is that way your saying.

Comment: yes~ if you are using javascript , jQuery etc. that's the way you just post.I'm showing the html way to do that.